# Relation between Curry-Howard isomorphism and Kripke semantics for intuitionistic logic

Tags: logic, type-theory, curry-howard

Intuitionistic logic(s) are usually defined in a purely synthetic way, with their own deduction rules different from classical logic, but they also have semantic interpretations.

One of them, more known in mathematical logic, is Kripke semantics, originated in modal logic, in which a formula is valid iff it holds in all Kripke frames.
Another interpretation, more known in computer science, is the Curry-Howard isomorphism, in which a proposition is interpretated as type in a suitable system and a proposition is valid iff there is a program of that type.

My question is: Is there any relation between these two interpretations? They are certainly equivalent, but merely concluding that from the two previous equivalences don't give any insight into a probably much deeper connection.

EDIT: Should I have posted this question in the Theoretical Computer Science Stack Exchange?

Comment: Why do you say that they are "certainly equivalent", and what does that mean, precisely?

Comment: We know that p is intuitionistically valid iff p is valid in all kripke frame and that p is intuitionistically valid iff the corresponding type is inhabited, thus p is valid in all kripke frame iff the corresponding type is inhabited. Thats all I meant by equivalent

Comment: What logic are you talking about? Propositional, predicate? It matters.

Comment: I mean, I could pose the question for both of them. For propositional you would use simply-typed lambda calculus and simple kripke frames, and for predicative you would use some system with dependent types and kripke frames with universal quantifiers. But for simplicity Im more interested in the propositional case.

Comment: By the way, congratulations for your fantastic essay introducing constructive mathematics. Its one of the reason that got me so interested in intuitionism and type theory!

Answer (score 1):

Both Kripke semantics and propositions-as-types interpretation are sound and complete for the intuitionistic propositional calculus. In this sense they are equivalent.

However, there are formulas in intuitionistic first-order logic (IHOL) which are valid under propositions-as-types but are not intuitionistically provable. See Remark 6.6. of [Propositions as [Types]](https://math.andrej.com/data/bracket_types.pdf), where the following formula is given:
$$
(\forall x . \exists y . R(x, y)) \Rightarrow
(\forall x, x' . \exists y, y' . R(x,y) \land R(x',y') \land (x = x' \Rightarrow y = y')).
$$
This is not provable intuitionistically, but it can be inhabited under propositions-as-types interpretation. Because Kripke semantics is complete for IHOL, the above formula provides a distinction between the two setups.